# Filling member function pointers in unordered_map to lookup functions based on strings

Tags: c++, lambda, unordered-map, pointer-to-member

I have a class which has certain member functions of different types.
Now I am trying to create an unordered_map of these members functions based on a std::string key.

I have got this far that if I create a lambda with no capture then it returns the function pointer to the member function. But I am not able to figure out how to put that address in the unordered_map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

typedef void (*DoIt)();

class first
{
    public:
        void func_1(){std::cout<<"print from func1"<<endl;};
        void print_number();
        int update_number();
        string get_name();
        void print_name();
        first(int num, string n){number = num; name = n;};
        ~first(){std::cout<<"print destructing."<<std::endl;};
    private:
        int number;
        string name;
};

void first::print_number()
{
    std::cout<<"number is:"<<number<<endl;
}

int first::update_number()
{
    number = number + 1;
    return number;
}

string first::get_name()
{
    return name;
}

void first::print_name()
{
    cout<<"name from print name is :"<<name<<endl;
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    first f{6, "JohnDoe"};
    f.func_1();
    f.print_number();
    cout<<"new number is :"<<f.update_number();
    std::cout<<"Hello World."<<std::endl;
    f.print_number();
    cout<<"name is :"<<f.get_name()<<endl;

    auto f1 = [](first& f) { f.print_name();};
    f1(f);
    auto f2 = [](first& f) { f.print_number();};    
    f2(f);
    
    unordered_map<string,DoIt> umap_ptr;
    umap_ptr["ptr_num"] = &f2;
    umap_ptr["ptr_name"] = &f1;
    
    
    unordered_map<string, int> umap;
    umap["p_num"] = 1;
    umap["p_name"] = 2;
    
    for (auto x : umap)
          cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(first& f)` your functions take an argument, but your map stores `void (*DoIt)();` functions with no argument. Don't you want to store `void (*)(first& f)` inside the map?

Comment: Your lambdas take `first` as argument, the DoIt functions are supposed to take nothing. Please specify what your intent is.

Comment: I am trying to get the function pointers of f.print_number() and f.print_name() into an unordered_map. And map those pointers to a keys ("p_num", "p_name"), and then when a string is passed I want to search through the map and call its respective function.

Comment: that's not how it's is done.  f.print_number() and f.print_name() don't have function pointers, they have pointer-to-member pointers. Lambda is a separate class and while technically you can wrap it around the call, you have type mismatch there, twice, First: lanbda's operator() doesn't take argument, so it cannot be cast to DoIt. Second, &f1, &f2 are pointers to a object of unnamed type, not to the function. You should not use & with lambdas or functions in C++.

Answer (score 1):

THe code is a mishmash of syntax, looking like  it's author not sure of precise condition when to use what.  Declaring captureless lambda, but using it as capturing ne afterwards in one of problems. Type mismatch and expression type mismatch are also problems.

A possible, but very ineffective solution can be:

```
// needs to be mutable because print_name isn't const-declared
auto f1 = [=]() mutable  { f.print_name();}; 
f1();
auto f2 = [=]() mutable  { f.print_number();};    
f2();

unordered_map<string,std::function<void()>> umap_ptr;
umap_ptr["ptr_num"] = f2;
umap_ptr["ptr_name"] = f1;
```

It's ineffective because `std::function` is a lambda-like wrapper around invocable. In our case it's lambda wrapper around lambda wrapper around member function call here.  Acceptable or not, it depends on purpose.

One can use pointer to member , but that would limit map to containing pointers of members belonging only to a single type:

```
unordered_map<string, void (first::*)()> umap_ptr;
umap_ptr["ptr_num"] = &first::print_number;
umap_ptr["ptr_name"] = &first::print_name;
```

And call to such would look esoteric.

```
(f.*umap_ptr["ptr_num"])();
```

Perhaps the REAL thing you're looking for is an implementation of visitor pattern.

Comment: My syntax does not clearly state the purpose. What I am looking for is a way to create an unordered_map of member functions. So the map would include a string which would be the key and the pointer to the member function. So based on a key (std::string) I could call the member function.

Comment: @user2225754   to member function of one type? or many types? Same type of function member or many, to members of related types? In general, that's a map of visitors but you need objects to invoke functions upon, and if map have to capture object its members are invoked with, then you can use lambda. member function doesn't have connection to an instance of object, you need an object too. In most general case you would need to have some kind of facility   doing type cast while map would store only void* because a function with different set of parameters is a different type.

Comment: member functions of one return type. The example I gave has two functions of the same type - void - that are not doing much but printing an output.

Comment: @user2225754 That doesn't make a lick of sense.  map can contain objects of SAME type only. Maybe you're you're not getting that. The return type,the class it belongs to and the list of parameters *together* define type of pointer to member. Change one of three, and you can't store them together. You may store them wrapped in something agnostic to their type, like `std::variant`, `std::any`, etc.  But then you have to do proper casts before calling. If all that you need is emulation `void()`  function and a copy of object would be stored in map - then the given example with lambda may work.

Comment: that is what I said, right now I am only focusing of member functions with one return type only - which is void.

Comment: @user2225754 and no argument, belonging only to that type? `unordered_map<string, void (first::*)()>`

Comment: yes no arguments also. I made the print functions a const now as well. All they do is print a number and a name.

Comment: in the implementation with a lambda , why does the lambda implementation call 4 destructors when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Sorry its calling 3 destructors for each of the lambda's created so a total of 6 desctructors..                          { 
  // needs to be mutable because print_name isn't const-declared
  auto f1_1 = [=](){ f.print_name();}; 
//  f1_1();
  auto f2_1 = [=](){ f.print_number();};    
//  f2_1();
  
  unordered_map<string, std::function<void()>> umap_ptr;
  umap_ptr["num"] = f2_1;
  umap_ptr["name"] = f1_1;
 }  could you tell me why ?

Comment: @user2225754 Here have a copy of object `first` named `f` in each lambda instance. Map contains own copies. That's why lambda solution with capture by value is inefficient unless there is very strong reasons to to so. If you can, you may use capture by reference but then you must be aware of  `f` lifespan.

Comment: thank you. I like the solution that only uses the references. But how do I access the function which is in the map?                                                                                                                                   { 
  for (auto x : umap_ptr)
        cout <<"map key is:"<<x.first<<":"<< endl;
        cout <<"map function is:"<<endl; 
 }

Comment: @user2225754 you simply call it? `x.second` is your function wrapper for every element, so you can call it `x.second()`. You can't use `<<` on it. Well, technically you can print address by using &, but that's it. Note that you do another copy if you write loop like that. You may want  `for (auto &x : umap_ptr)`

Comment: I was looking for an example in which I could make this unordered_map implementation a separate class, so that the implementation can be made common and be applied to other situations that requires searching.

Comment: I modified the code now -  I put the lambdas inside the constructor of a class (the class whose member functions I am trying to access via unordered map)                                                                                                                                      auto f1_1 = [&](){ Student::print_name();}; 
auto f2_1 = [&](){ Student::print_number();}; 
auto f3_1 = [&](){ Student::print_address();};
umap_ptr[lookup_n::table[0]] = f2_1;
umap_ptr[lookup_n::table[1]] = f1_1;
umap_ptr[lookup_n::table[2]] = f3_1;

Answer (score 0):

Use utilities from `<functional`>. Raw pointers are raw - you have to create an actual function at file scope for them. `std::function` allows adding additional information to the function pointer - like a lambda, or other class, for example.

```
unordered_map<string, std::function<void()>> umap_ptr;
umap_ptr["ptr_num"] = std::bind(&first::print_name, f);
umap_ptr["ptr_name"] = std::bind(&first::print_number, f);
```

Comment: question is...why using lambdas at this point?

Comment: In this case why does the class destructor get called 6 times?                                                                                                      {
  unordered_map<string, std::function<void()>> umap_ptr;
  umap_ptr["ptr_num"] = std::bind(&first::print_number, f);
  umap_ptr["ptr_name"] = std::bind(&first::print_name, f);
 }